# How to link two JavaScript files together? NO HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have File1.js that has the main functions for my program. I also have File2.js that has extra functions that I didn't want to include in File1.js because I feel it would be easier to edit the functions in a separate file. Is it possible to call a function in File1.js and have the function defined in File2.js? If so, how can I link the two files together?

Comment: You could look into using a build tool to concatenate the files together. Otherwise, if you have both file1.js and file2.js linked to in a HTML document, all methods in file1.js should be available within file2.js.

Comment: OP asked without HTML, as he is writing for discord.js, which requires no HTML code

Comment: As you've tagged this `node.js`, the mention of `HTML` is confusing - since node.js is not a browser, therefore there is no HTML

Comment: nodejs supports [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: Question has been answered! Thank you. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by declaring exports like so:

```js
/* utils.js */
module.exports = {
  doSomething: function() {
    // code
  },

  anotherOne: function() {
    // code
  }
};
```

```js
/* index.js */
const utils = require('./utils.js');
utils.doSomething();
```